# html5 - Microdata - Adding book to an author (not vice versa)

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I'm tagging a site with Schema.org microdata, and have run into a quandry. I understand that I can define a book and then it's author (I'll use ../ rather than http://schema.org/ for space):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="../Book">
<span itemprop="name">Charlie and the Chocolate Factory</span>
written by <span itemprop="author">Roald Dahl</span>
</div>
```

But I'm tagging a page about the author, so I want a way to list his books and say that all these items are written by him, without listing his name over and over again:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="../Person" id="main">
<h1 itemprop="name">Roald Dahl</h1>
<p>His books included <span itemscope itemtype="../Book">Charlie and the
Chocolate Factory</span> and 
<span itemscope itemtype="../Book">James and the Giant Peach</span></p>
</article>
```

Any ideas? Just putting *itemref="main"* doesn't help (because I'm trying to give a specific relation, that of author, not just relate these two things generally). Does an empty span element make any sense?:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="../Book">James and the Giant Peach
<span itemprop="author" itemref="main"></span></span>
```

**UPDATE**: I think I've figured this one out, for anyone looking up. You can define an itemprop for an itemscope, to be used later with itemref. So I think the answer is:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="../Person" itemprop="author" id="main">
<h1 itemprop="name">Roald Dahl</h1>
<p>His books included <span itemscope itemtype="../Book" itemref="main">Charlie
and the Chocolate Factory</span> and 
<span itemscope itemtype="../Book" itemref="main">James and the Giant Peach</span>
</article>
```

Not sure what I'd do if there was more than one itemprop I wanted to link back (Schema.org is full on 2-way relationships with only one of those ways defined) but this solves my particular problem.

**UPDATE2** : This has solved my previous problem, but I cannot now embed this within any other itemscopes. So, I want to tag the whole thing as an *Article*, I can't do it as:

```
<main itemscope itemtype="../Article">
<article itemscope itemtype="../Person" itemprop="author" id="main">
<h1 itemprop="name">Roald Dahl</h1>
....
</article></main>
```

Now my itemprop="author" hack is also assigned to the top level *Article*. Now my code is telling people that Roald Dahl wrote not only the books given, but this article itself!

Any suggestions how to solve this, or a solution to my original problem that doesn't cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about your issue I've came to two (both are a bit awkward) solutions. Sharing my thoughts.

So answering your original question. You may say that your _*author* _*writes* _*books* and use new http://schema.org/WriteAction class. Its description

> The act of authoring written creative content.

suits your use case. Actually it is covered in example at the page.

Then we can do smth like:

```
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <article  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WriteAction">
        <div itemprop="agent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <h1 itemprop="name">Roald Dahl</h1>
        </div>
        <p>His books included <span itemprop="result" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book"><span itemprop="name">Charlie and the Chocolate Factory</span></span> and 
        <span itemprop="result" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book"><span itemprop="name">James and the Giant Peach</span></span></p>
    </article>
</main>
```

Next thought is about your updated question. I don't see other option than duplicate part of the data in invisible tags somewhere on the page not covered by *Article*. But maybe I'm missing smth.
E.g.,

```
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <article>
        <h1>Roald Dahl</h1>
        <p>His books included <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemref="main">
            <span itemprop="name">Charlie and the Chocolate Factory</span></span>
        and 
        <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemref="main">
            <span itemprop="name">James and the Giant Peach</span></span></p>
    </article>
</main>
<!-- in the footer or any other place -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemprop="author" id="main">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Roald Dahl"/>
</div>
```

Both solutions are not SO nice but both work.

Comment: Thanks for those, unfortunately my second problem gets in the way of both solutions. It's a page all about Roald Dahl ([here it is pre-Microdata'd](http://www.spartacus.schoolnet.co.uk/SPYdahl.htm) if you're curious). So I really need the whole article inside the Person itemscope, since I'm setting itemprops for spouse, parents, affiliations and more. Solution 1 would require a million itemrefs to assign Roald Dahl to all these itemprops. Solution 2 would define half my semantic links (spouse, parents etc) to one Person object, and the book information to another object with the same name.

Comment: One more option is to make an extension (http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) to get classes and properties you need. Or change your requirements (e.g., don't use Article).

Comment: On balance I'll go for your solution 2. It keeps the code simple, and you'd hope any search engine would figure that two objects named Roald Dahl are the same thing (especially since, as in this case, the knowledge is probably in their database).

I thought I might also create an "authored" extension on the Person class. Is it OK to just put that as an itemprop? The Google Structured Data Tool will show errors - should I just ignore that?

Comment: Yes for both. Smth like 

*<div itemprop="agent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person/Author">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Roald Dahl</h1>
  <span itemprop="book">Book1</span>
</div>*      Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it'd helped you :)